# How Can I use combination of inner join and order by

Tags: mysql

How Can I use combination of inner join and order by.

My query is running but my output is not giving me the correct answer, im having problem with this line, how can I sort 1 column or the column `cm_status` only:

```
INNER JOIN dbfeedersystem.tblrepair on 
tblpm.control_number_pm=tblrepair.control_number

SELECT tblfeeder.control_number AS Control_No,tblfeeder.serial_number AS
Serial_No,tblfeeder.model AS Model,
DATE_FORMAT(date_updated_pm,'%d-%b-%Y') AS PM_Date,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(due_date,INTERVAL 1 WEEK),'%d-%b-%Y') AS Issuance_of_Recall,
DATE_FORMAT(due_date,'%d-%b-%Y') AS Due_Date, pm_status, cm_status
FROM dbfeedersystem.tblpm INNER JOIN dbfeedersystem.tblrepair on 
tblpm.control_number_pm=tblrepair.control_number
INNER JOIN 
dbfeedersystem.tblfeeder on 
tblpm.control_number_pm=tblfeeder.control_number 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT control_number_pm,max(date_updated_pm) AS date_updated_pm FROM
dbfeedersystem.tblpm GROUP BY control_number_pm)
AS MAX USING (control_number_pm,date_updated_pm) 
ORDER BY date_updated_pm,control_number_pm;
```

Comment: Try adding `cm_status` column in `order by`!

Comment: I know that will work but I want is, in this part I can sort for this column only. INNER JOIN dbfeedersystem.tblrepair on tblpm.control_number_pm=tblrepair.control_number

Comment: INNER JOIN dbfeedersystem.tblrepair on 
tblpm.control_number_pm=tblrepair.control_number